# Equivalent of a boxplot for normally distributed data?

Tags: r, data-visualization, boxplot, nonparametric

If I plot some data in function of a categorical variable in R, I get the standard boxplot. However, the boxplot displays non-parametric statistics (quantiles) that don't seem appropriate for normally distributed data.

What is the equivalent of the boxplot for normally distributed data (ideally, something based on confidence intervals?) ? How do I get these plots with R?

Comment: A couple of questions: Why do you think that quantiles are inappropriate for normally distributed data? What do you mean by "equivalent of the boxplot for normally distributed data" (i.d. say the equivalent is the boxplot)? Would you care to explain what you mean by "ideally, something based on confidence intervals" (confidence interval for what)?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure the quantiles are the most meaningful way to represent variation of data of a known distribution. Maybe displaying the 95% CI (range in which 95% of the points will fall in?) would be more meaningful? But if the answer is "the standard boxplot is OK", that's not a problem for me. I just want to hear it from qualified people :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I agree with Momo's comments.  Boxplots are appropriate for normally distributed data as well as any other distribution for continuous variables.  There is no relevance to confidence intervals when discussing boxplots for sample data.

However I think there are ways to customize boxplots to normal distributions by adding lines to show 1 sigma and 2 sigma points and compare them the 68th and 95th percentiles that they should match for normally distributed data.

Comment: Those customized boxplots are pretty much what I had in mind. Would you happen to know how to get them with R?

Comment: Sorry, hopefully an R expert can help you with that.

Comment: I found a way with ggplot2: http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Graphs/Plotting%20means%20and%20error%20bars%20%28ggplot2%29/

Comment: static, that link doesn't display any boxplots at all! Do you perhaps have a different understanding of [what a boxplot is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot) than others do?

Answer (score 6):

Plotting categorical vs continuous variables with box-and-whiskers plots is, as far as I know, fairly common and appropriate for normally distributed data.

That said, you might be interested in adding additional information (although again, what follows applies to non-normally distributed data as well):

Beyond the question of where the compared distribution peak, getting an idea of the dispersion and the skewness of your data is important. Boxplots will give you some insight into that (by comparing interquartile ranges and the symmetry of each boxplot, for instance), but this remains limited.

Using violin plots, for instance, give you a detailed view of the kernel density of your distribution, and thus highlight "better" the underlying distributions compared to boxplots.

In R, you can use the `ggplot2` library, and use a `geom_violin()` layer.

```
require(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg))
p + geom_violin()
p + geom_boxplot(notch=T) # if you want to compare
```

You can also overlay your plots with additional information (e.g. position of mean and standard deviation).

To plot the 1st sigma:

```
up <- function(x){ mean(x,na.rm=T) + sd(x,na.rm=T)}
down <- function(x){ mean(x,na.rm=T) - sd(x,na.rm=T)}

p <- p + geom_violin() +
stat_summary(geom="point", fun.y= up, size=4, colour="gray50", shape=0,data=mtcars) +
stat_summary(geom="point", fun.y= mean, size=4, colour="gray50", shape=16,data=mtcars) +
stat_summary(geom="point", fun.y= down, size=4, colour="gray50", shape=0,data=mtcars)
```

I hope this helps.